# Linking to an older version of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple instated the following policy:

> Apps linked on or after iOS 15 are limited to a maximum of 50 entries
> in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)

Is there a way to link to an earlier iOS version (like iOS 14.1) but release on the App Store and download on iPhones with iOS 15 installed to get around this measure?

How does one link to an earlier version of iOS?

Comment: The simplest way is to build with Xcode 12, but that will probably only be supported for another few months as rudedog said

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your target SDK to be iOS 14 but why bother? If the past is any guide, Apple will soon stop accepting app submissions unless they’re linked against iOS 15. So whatever your use case is for so many entries, you’re going to have to find a workaround.

Comment: Setting target to older versions enable people with old iPhone or iPhone that can not be upgraded (some enterprise may want some time before update their iPhone OS)

Comment: The SDK you use doesn't affect the iOS versions your app supports. You can support iOS 9 devices while linking to the iOS 15 SDK.